# How to export security and index rules from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've set up multiple different indexes on my Firestore development database. Now, I would like to export them into the `firestore.indexes.json` so that the process of setting up prod environment would be easier. Is there a way to export those indexes using Firebase CLI? The same applies to security rules, although I know that I can copy paste them.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In your Firebase project folder execute this in the terminal:

```
firebase firestore:indexes > firestore.indexes.json
```

And it will save a file called **firestore.indexes.json** with your indexes.

You can then upload that file onto other Firebase projects.

Comment: then how do you `deploy` specific json file to different db?

Answer (score 192):

It's possible!

Run from CLI `firebase firestore:indexes` inside your firebase project folder.

Providing you have indexes already setup and logged into Firebase via the CLI too, you'll get a formatted JSON output for you to copy.

Example:

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionId": "teslaData",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "Model",
          "mode": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "Price",
          "mode": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Exported indexes can be re imported using `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`. Check following doc extract.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

> You can also deploy indexes with the Firebase CLI. To get started, run
> firebase init firestore in your project directory. During setup, the
> Firebase CLI generates a JSON file with the default indexes in the
> correct format. Edit the file to add more indexes and deploy it with
> the firebase deploy command. If you only want to deploy indexes, add
> the --only firestore:indexes flag. If you make edits to the indexes
> using the Firebase console, make sure you also update your local
> indexes file.

I'm using Firebase CLI `4.2.1` if that helps.

Edit: It's still working as of `9.6.0`.

Comment: That's a great find @fyllepo! I'd completely missed that you can use `firestore:indexes` to **read** the indexes. I'm struggling to get it to work, but it seems that's just on me. Did you get it to work? If so, I assume the JSON file contains only the indexes, and not the security rules. Is that correct? Can you maybe update your answer to show what the JSON contains?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added an example, thank you for the tip :)

Comment: This no longer works. Results come back in a different format:
"indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "posts",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "createdBy",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "createdAt",
          "order": "DESCENDING"
        }
      ]
    },

Comment: @TroyMichael I haven't used Firebase for a little while, can you mention your firebase version and I'll investigate shortly?

Comment: This worked for me using firebase-tools (firebase-cli) 8.7.0.

Comment: Yup, still works on version 9.6.0 too. Thanks

Comment: Use it like this : firebase firestore:indexes > firestore.indexes.json

Answer (score 11):

This is how my project files are laid out

`myProjectFolder`

- `.firebaserc`
- `firebase.json`
- `firestore.indexes.json`
- `functions`

---

- Run the commands `firebase use myApp-dev` then `firebase firestore:indexes > firestore.indexes.json` to export your current dev project's indexes to a file

  - `myApp-dev` and `myApp-prod` is the "Project ID".  To find it in Firebase, click the cog wheel next to "Project Overview" --> Project settings --> General tab (you should see it below)

In file `firebase.json` make sure it is pointing to the exported `firestore.indexes.json` for its indexes:

```json
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

- Run the commands `firebase use myApp-prod` and `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is currently an API for getting the Firestore security rules from a project. You can [**deploy** rules through the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deployment), which can also be embedded in custom Node scripts, and invoked from CI processes. But as far as I know there is no API to read the rules from a project.

It sounds like a good reason to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 1):

If the accepted answer isn't working for you (I got a permissions error) for firestore indexes you can go to your firebase console > Cloud firestore > Indexes then open up the network tab in inspector, clear all the requests and refresh the page. Once the page is loaded you can find the JSON formatted response of the indexes (I found mine by searching the word 'indexes' in the search bar of the network tab) in the XHR filter of network requests. It should look something like 'indexes?key=...' you can copy this JSON response.

If you've already initialized firebase in your project with `firebase init`, you can simply paste it into your project's firestore.indexes.json file.
Then change each name property to a collectionGroup property. eg: `'name': 'projects/[your project name]...'` to `'collectionGroup': '[name of collection for this index]'`

Run `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes` to update any changes made in your text editor back to the firestore indexes tab

for firestore security rules, in a less complicated but similar manner, you can copy and paste the rules shown in the firebase console into the firestore.rules file of your project.

sample `firestore.indexes.json` file

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "faq",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "searchKeywords",
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "answered",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "relevanceScore",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "__name__",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To export composite indexes in json format using gcloud console use

```
gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format json
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/indexes

Answer (score -18):

The [Cloud Firestore Index Definition Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firestore/indexes/) page shows how.

> You can export indexes with the CLI using firebase
> `firestore:indexes`.